# Unlike other major JS frameworks such as Angular, why does ReactJS need so many external tools to build an app?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I've been coding React for the last couple of months now. I thought, initially, just going through the React official docs would be sufficient. But I've had to learn some other tools in order to really make my apps useful/easier to developer. For example, tools like Redux and react-router. How come these tools don't already come with React officially? What's the true purpose of React vs other JS frameworks?

Comment: It all comes down to the ecosystem chosen by the developers.  There's sort of a recent explosion of tools out there in JavaScript.  Each carries a few opinions on how something should be, while also bringing the benefit of not having to reinvent something.  Most of the folks developing these complex frameworks are also comfortable with many of these tools, and the barrier to entry for them is low.  It's not always so low for the people downstream, however.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking for an opinion-based response.

Comment: React doesn't "need" redux or react-router, you've elected to use them. Those add ons don't come with React because not all projects that use React need or want them, so it's best that they don't ship with React...

Answer (score 1):

ReactJs is not a framework ,it's a JavaScript library and it's not a language ,it's build upon JavaScript . It's a way to solve your common problems and complex tasks easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs/Angular is a fully fledged framework - it gives you built-in solutions for promises ($q), ajax calls ($http), routing and intra-component communication via services amongst others.

Reactjs on the other hand is much less opinionated. It provides a mechanism to layout and structure view code and practically nothing else (from the list above). So it's much lighter weight and you are much freer to use other libraries/packages where you feel it is necessary.

Comment: I've heard the word 'opinionated' used a lot when it comes to JS frameworks/libraries. Do you mind going into a bit more as to what that means?